# Can I change the number of hidden nodes in my Deep Learning model instead of remaking the entire model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, out-of-memory, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying a brute force grid search to find the optimal number of hidden nodes to have in my TensorFlow DeepLearning model. I'm not too concerned about how long the program will take but I've found that my program runs out of memory because of all the tf.variables it has to make. The code to build my model is as follows:

```
def hiddenLayer(input_data, num_nodes, num_inputs, layer_num):
    #Initialize all weights as the standard deviation of the input
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_inputs, num_nodes],
        stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(num_inputs))), name='hidden' + str(layer_num) + '_weights')
    #Initialize all biases as zero
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_nodes]), name='hidden' + str(layer_num) + '_biases')
    #Using RELU, return a linear combination of the biases and weights
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input_data, weights) + biases)



def softmaxOutput(input_data, num_inputs, num_outputs):
    #Initialize all weights as the standard deviation of the input
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_inputs, num_outputs], 
        stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(num_inputs))), name='output_weights')
    #Initialize all baises as zero
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_outputs]), name='output_biases')
    #Squash the linear combination using softmax to give you LOGITS
    return tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(input_data, weights) + biases)

def calculate_loss(logits, labels):
    labels = tf.to_int64(labels)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits, labels, name = 'xentropy'))


class SingleDNNClassifier(object):
    def __init__(self, num_nodes, num_inputs, num_outputs, batch_size, layer_num=1, lr=0.01):
    #Defining the features and labels variables
        self.x = x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_inputs))
        self.y = y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(batch_size))
        #Run the input data through the first hidden layer
        x = hiddenLayer(x, num_nodes, num_inputs, layer_num)
        #Run the output from the first hidden layer with softmax to get predicted logits
        self.logits = logits = softmaxOutput(x, num_nodes, num_outputs)
        #Get the predicted labels
        self.predictions = tf.argmax(logits,1)
        #Calculate the loss
        self.loss = xeloss = calculate_loss(logits, y)
        #Define the training operation for this model
        self.train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr).minimize(xeloss)


def train(sess, model, data, batch_size):
    epoch_size = int(data.num_samples/batch_size)
    losses = []

    for step in xrange(epoch_size):
        #The way you get batches now shuffles the data, check to see if this is correct
        train_x, train_y = data.next_batch(batch_size)
        loss, _ = sess.run([model.loss, model.train_op],
            {model.x: train_x, model.y: train_y})
        losses.append(loss)
        if step % (epoch_size/5) == 5:
            tf.logging.info("%.2f: %.3f", step * 1.0 / epoch_size, np.mean(losses))
    return np.mean(losses)


def evaluate(sess, model, data, batch_size):
    predicted_values = []
    actual_values = []

    for i in xrange(int(data.num_samples/batch_size)):
        val_x, val_y = data.next_batch(batch_size)
        predictions = sess.run(model.predictions, {model.x: val_x, model.y: val_y})
        predicted_values.append(predictions)
        actual_values.append(val_y)
    predicted_values = np.concatenate(predicted_values).ravel()
    actual_values = np.concatenate(actual_values).ravel()

    return roc_auc_score(actual_values, predicted_values)
```

As you can see, my model is pretty simple. Just a single layer network with a softmax output. However, I want to know the optimal number of hidden nodes so I am running this code:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

hidden_nodes = 100
epochs = 100
increment = 100
max_hidden_nodes = 20000

while (hidden_nodes <= max_hidden_nodes):
    print ("HIDDEN NODES: %d\n" %(hidden_nodes))
    output_file = open('AUC_SingleLayer/SingleLayer_' + str(hidden_nodes) + '.txt', 'w')
    model = SingleDNNClassifier(hidden_nodes,16000,2,100)

    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    for i in range(epochs):
        print ("\tEPOCH: %d\n" %(i+1))
        train(sess, model, dataset.training, 100)
        valid_auc = DLM.evaluate(sess, model, dataset.testing, 100)
        output_file.write('EPOCH %d: %.5f' % (i+1, valid_auc))
        if (i < epochs-1):
            output_file.write('\n')
    hidden_nodes += increment
```

However, I keep getting an error that my Linux workstation runs out of memory because it has to keep reinitializing the weights and biases variables within my *hiddenLayer* function. Naturally, as the number of nodes increases, the more memory each variable is going to take.

I'm trying to do something like in this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2311

where I can just pass in the value to a placeholder of an unspecified size for the dimension that I am changing but am not sure if it will work. I'd appreciate any help or direction with this.

TLDR: Need to stop reinitializing variables because i am running out of memory but the variable's size is going to change for each iteration of my while loop.

Comment: Can you create a large model without the grid search? If you can't then its not an issue with your grid search but simply your memory not being enough. Maybe I'm missing something here, please excuse me if I did.

Comment: I can create the model without the grid search. The problem is that I'm recreating the model in every iteration of the grid search since I have a different number of hidden nodes in every iteration. So the variables created in one iteration take up some memory and so as the iterations of my grid search continues, I start to run out of memory as the previous variables start to accumulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this isn't a perfect answer, I managed to find a workaround. I wrote a shell script that gets a range of numbers based on my interval using the *seq starting_number increment ending_number* and fed each value into my python code as a command line parameter. This avoids the memory problem since each iteration ends with closing the python process, thus, avoiding the memory problem.